# The functional calculus on continuous functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let us consider $C[0,1]$ the space of continuous functions on the closed unit interval. For a given $x$  in $C[0,1]$, let us consider  $A(sp(x))$, all analytic functions on a neighborhood of $sp(x)$.

> Q. Is $\{f(x): f\in A(sp(x))\}$ the same as the Banach algebra generated by $x$ in $C[0,1]$?

Comment: What is $sp(x)$?

Comment: $sp(x)$ is the spectrum of $x$, consists of all complex numbers $t$ such that $t1-x$ is not invertible.

Comment: Try the identity function for $x$.